# code for a matlab tone filter not working

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write a matlab code to design a firfilter for my signals matlab class but I am having trouble getting the filter to work this code below is supposed to determine the frequencies and filter them out of the sunshinesquare.wav file. however when I go to run the program matlab tells me there is an error with the notchfilter line but I can't figure out what is wrong with it any suggestions/help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my matlab code

```
[x, fs] = audioread('SunshineSquare.wav'); 
 
X = fft(x); 
f = linspace(0, fs/2, length(X)/2);
[~, f0] = max(abs(X(1:length(X)/2))); 
 
notchFilter = fdesign.notch('N,Fc', 100, f0, fs); 
b = firpm(notchFilter); 

 
y = filter(b, 1, x); 


sound(x, fs);
```

NEW CODE

```
[x, fs] = audioread('SunshineSquare.wav'); 
x = y; fs = Fs;
X = fft(x); 
L = floor(length(X)/2);
f = linspace(0, fs/2, L);
[~, f0idx] = max(abs(X(1:L))); 
f0 = (f0idx-1)/L;
Q = 2.5;
notchFilter1 = fdesign.notch('N,F0,Q', 6, f0, Q); 
notchFilter2 = fdesign.notch('N,F0,Q', 6, f0*2, Q);
Hd1 = design(notchFilter1, 'SystemObject', true);
Hd2 = design(notchFilter2, 'SystemObject', true);
y = Hd2(Hd1(x));
sound(y, fs)
tiledlayout('flow');
nexttile
plot(f, abs(X(1:L))); title('original spectrum');
nexttile
Y = fft(y);
plot(f, abs(Y(1:L))); title('filtered spectrum');
```

Comment: What error does it tell you?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: If you check the documentation, you'll see that `'N,Fc'` is not a valid spec.  https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/fdesign.notch.html

Comment: Okay not sure what to replace that with would that be the frequency?

Comment: If you just want to provide N, F0, Q and Fs, just provide those four numbers.  You don't need the spec string at all.

Comment: Okay I'll Try that thanks!

Comment: Okay so I am able filter out the tone on a plot but I am still unable to filter out the tone in the wav.file this is my code so far any idea's of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Code is posted in the original question